# Why do I need to use $() ? What is it purpose?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I am currently trying to understand a piece of code, though I don't understand the use of `$()` inside my code. My question might be stupid, and I am sorry if it is the case.

Here's more details : 
There's an object, named `p_Element`, which has two properties (target and menu). Then, there's this line :

```
let l_Element = $(p_Element.target);
```

I tried replacing it by :

```
let l_Element = p_Element.target;
```

but the script doesn't seem to execute.

So here's my question: What is the difference between these two lines? What does `$(p_Element.target)` returns?

In case you need more details, here's the piece of code I am trying to understand :

```
var l_Targets = [
    {target: "#pve",            menu: ".pve"},
    {target: "#tutorial",       menu: ".tutorial"},
    {target: "#donation_home",  menu: ".donation"},
    {target: "#register",       menu: ".register"},
    {target: "#account_top",    menu: ".team"},
    {target: "#races",          menu: ".races"}
];
var l_Infos = {};
l_Targets.forEach(function(p_Element)
{
    let l_Element = $(p_Element.target); // Please explain me this line
    if (l_Element.length === 0 || l_Element.length > 1)
        return;
    let l_Top    = parseInt(l_Element.offset().top);
    let l_Bottom = parseInt(l_Element.offset().top + l_Element.height());
    l_Infos[p_Element.target] = {
        top: l_Top,
        bottom: l_Bottom,
        menu: p_Element.menu
    };

});
```

I don't own this script, it comes from here: https://naicaonline.com/assets/js/home/navbar.js?v=0.08

Comment: `$` calling an element returns a jQuery object containing that element. jQuery methods can't be used on plain elements, and vice versa.

Comment: `$` represents [jQuery](https://jquery.com) which is basically a wrapper for a lot of common front end JavaScript functions. But primarily for DOM related functions.

Comment: Guys, abstain from answering in comments please and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let l_Element = $(p_Element.target); // This returns a JQuery Object.
```

This is equal to `document.getElementById(p_Element.target); //but you need to remove # because in JQuery # this char is used to select dom elements by ID and . is used to select dom elements by class`

JQuery makes the native JS command short and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is the name of a function. `$(...)` calls that function.

It's not something built into JavaScript. In principle you could define your own variable or function and call it `$`, but in practice it's probably the one provided by [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). See [this link](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) for an introduction.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *jQuery selector*, and here's how the specific one you're using works:

```
let l_Element = $(p_Element.target);
```

It assigns the block scope variable `l_Element` to `$(p_Element.target)`. `p_Element` is the current item used in the `forEach` loop, and `.target` is the `target` property of `p_Element`. Look at the array `l_Targets` - here's what each iteration over it will make `l_Element` equal to:

```
var l_Targets = [
    {target: "#pve",            menu: ".pve"},
    {target: "#tutorial",       menu: ".tutorial"},
    {target: "#donation_home",  menu: ".donation"},
    {target: "#register",       menu: ".register"},
    {target: "#account_top",    menu: ".team"},
    {target: "#races",          menu: ".races"}
];
```

Each value of `l_Element` will change depending on the current iteration. Here's what the values will be:

```
l_Element = $("#pve"); //1st iteration
l_Element = $("#tutorial"); //2nd iteration
l_Element = $("#donation_home"); //3rd iteration
l_Element = $("#register"); //4th iteration
l_Element = $("#account_top"); //5th iteration
l_Element = $("#races"); //6th iteration
```

Find out more about jQuery [here](https://jquery.com).